# Angular Js How to encode and decode special characters in response result?

Tags: angularjs

I am working on to save data and user can enter data with special character also.I have encode the name string when saving data but in response json array is coming. How we can decode the data again when get the response.

Js to save the data with encoded string.

```
$scope.saveData = function(){

        $scope.loading = true;
        $scope.Name = encodeURI(this.group.name); 
        $scope.Name1 = encodeURIComponent($scope.groupName);
        $scope.groupData = 'Name='+$scope.Name1+'&Users='+$scope.UserID.join();
        DataService.createUsers($scope.groupData).success(function (data) {

        }).catch(function (err) { 

        })
        .finally(function () {

        });
    }
```

Js to get the data of users in controller.

```
localStorageService.set('users', grps.allUsers);
localStorageService.bind($scope, 'users');  

function getMyUsers(){
    DataService.getMyUsers().then(function successCallback(response) 
    {

        $scope.users.length = 0; 
        $scope.users.push({'data': response.data.results});

    },function errorCallback(response) {

        console.log(response);

    });  
}

<ul>
 <li ng-repeat="user in users[0].data track by $index"> 
<div class="list_left">
    <div class="pro_text">  
        <h2 class="group_title"><a href="javascript:;">{{ usr.Name }}</a></h2> 

        <p class=""></p>
        <span>Created By: {{ user.createdBy.ownerName }} {{ user.createdBy.lastName }}</span> 
    </div>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `decodeURIComponent`

```
var response = {};
DataService.createUsers($scope.groupData).success(function (data) {
     data.yourArray.forEach(function(key, value){
         response[decodeURIComponent(key[0])] = decodeURIComponent(key[1]);
     });
   console.log("new response", response);
})
```

Comment: I need to decode the string in getMyUsers function.I have tried to use it in this function but not working